# Как центрировать надпись у логотипа

Tags: html, sass, центрирование

Хочу центрировать текст у логотипа как на картинке. Подскажите, как это лучше сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import "vars"
@import "fonts"
@import "libs"

body
    overflow-x: hidden
    position: relative
    margin: 0

header
    height: 100vh
    background:
        image: url("../img/bg-image.png")
        size: cover
        position: center

.content
    left: 80px
    position: absolute

.top-line
    margin-top: 44px
    font-size: 15px
    p
        text-transform: uppercase
        font-family: $default-font1
        color: #fff
        margin-left: 37px
        margin-bottom: 0
        &:nth-child(1)
            font-weight: 400
        &:last-child
            font-weight: 800
            white-space: nowrap
            margin-top: -26px

@import "media" // Always at the end
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Date Service Manager</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="content">
   <div class="top-line">
    <img src="../img/logo1.svg" alt="Dart Service Manager">
    <p>Dart</p><br>
    <p>Service Manager</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не понятно, приведите минимальный пример, а не код из вашего приложения. т.е. выложите картинку в интернет и оптимизируйте sass код для этой проблемы, неизвестно что может быть в vars, media, итд.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант не изобретать велосипеды, а использовать флексы.
Ваши `p` возьмите в `div`.

Ниже пример на чистом CSS, но, я думаю, поймёте, что делать...

```css
/* То, что центрирует */
.top-line {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Дальше ненужный код, просто чтобы пример был нормальный */
.top-line > img {
  background: #555; 
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

.top-line > div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-line">
  <img src="../img/logo1.svg" alt="Dart Service Manager">
  <div>
    <p>Dart</p>
    <p>Service Manager</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Comment: @nickita222a444, тогда примите, пожалуйста, ответ.